# No SSH/Telnet after reboot

Tags: ssh

I have a problem on my Raspberry PI B+ NOOBS. After a reboot I'm not able to log into Raspberry via SSH or Telnet. I have a static IP on WiFi an eth0 interfaces. I can see them in arp cache of the router and I can ping them. I can get connection only if a remove the power supply and I plug in once again. Any idea?
I used `reboot` and `reboot -f`.

I have connected:

- USB Stick
- WIFI usb antenna

Comment: Being able to ping the pi doesn't mean it actually rebooted -- it could be hung at some point in the shutdown process, such that services are mostly down but the interface is still up and responsive to ping.   Presuming you are using Raspbian (via NOOBs), you could confirm this one way or the other by looking through `/var/log/syslog`.   Look for `kernel: [       0.000000]`,  that's boot.   A few lines above that will be messages indicating a shutdown -- or not, if it never happened (meaning it was running when you pulled the plug).   If so, there may be messages about the problem.

Comment: Actually there's a complication there: since the pi doesn't have a clock, it may *appear* to reboot in the log but have hung, and you won't be able to tell by the timestamps since the first ones after boot are approximations.   The clearest method would be to keep track of exactly when you `reboot`, then wait and do the unplug/plug, then check how many boots occurred in the middle.   If there is just one, it never rebooted.

Comment: Hi, That's what I got from logs
That's what I got form logs after shutdown -r now
May  7 17:38:22 raspberrypi shutdown[2282]: shutting down for system reboot
May  7 17:38:22 raspberrypi init: Switching to runlevel: 6
May  7 17:38:23 raspberrypi ifplugd(eth0)[1561]: Killing child.
May  7 17:38:24 raspberrypi syslog-ng[1997]: syslog-ng shutting down; version='3.3.5'
May  7 17:38:41 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0

Comment: I think you are going to need a screen and keyboard attached to diagnose this; the logger shut down (this is necessary to unmount the filesystem), so there would have been no messages about any problem after that.

Comment: I'll do that. I think is something more durig the bring up procedure because I can see the IP l

Comment: I found the problem but not the solution: from consol logs, during the shutdown process, it tries to deconfigure network interface and it sucks in that process until I manually reboot it. Just for remind, I have etho and wan0 interfaces connected

Answer (score 2):

Your system might be stuck because of your usb stick : maybe the unmount process failed.

Try typing :

```
   sudo -i 
   echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq 
   echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

- The first command makes you go root
- The second command tells the kernel that you want to enable SysRq access (it’s usually disabled).
- The third command is equivalent to pressing Alt-SysRq-b (b is only for querty and azerty keyboard, go to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key for other keyboard)